# How to make a Matlab structure constant once it is already created?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a function defined in `foo.m`. This function can take a parameter `thing` of type `struct`. Once `foo` makes changes to `thing`, I want to "lock" `thing` so that it can no longer be changed. I essentially want to make it constant. I want to do this to ensure it isn't modified further down the line. How do I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: Good if you don't know what form your struct will have in advance**

You could 'capture' that variable with an anonymous function handle and only refer to your structure with that from now on. An anonymous function handle captures the state of the workspace at the time it is created. You will be able to access its elements as if it were the original struct, but if you try to assign to it, you'll generate an error.

E.g.

```
>> S_.a = 1;
>> S_.b = 2;
>> S = @() S_;
>> S_.a = 3;
>> S_
S_ =
  scalar structure containing the fields:
    a =  3
    b =  2
>> S()
ans =
  scalar structure containing the fields:
    a =  1
    b =  2
```

It's almost identical in syntax, except for the annoyance that you'll have to call it with `()`. 
I've used it on the terminal here, but obviously it can easily also be used in the context of a function.

Small caveat; if you **redefine** and overwrite the anonymous function, obviously, this backfires, since it will inherit whatever new workspace it had access to at the time of the redefinition.

**Solution 2: Good if you know your struct's form in advance:**

Assume you know in advance that your struct will only contain fields `a` and `b`. Create a class with the same properties restricting 'SetAccess', e.g.

```
classdef ConstStruct
  properties (GetAccess = 'public', SetAccess = 'private')
    a
    b
  end

  methods
    %constructor
    function obj = ConstStruct(S)
      obj.a = S.a;
      obj.b = S.b;
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your main code:

```
>> MyStruct = struct('a',1,'b',2)
MyStruct = 
    a: 1
    b: 2
>> MyStruct = ConstStruct(MyStruct)
MyStruct = 
  ConstStruct with properties:
    a: 1
    b: 2
>> MyStruct.a
ans =
     1
>> MyStruct.a = 2
You cannot set the read-only property 'a' of 'ConstStruct'.
```

Comment: @physmom I updated with a more elegant solution, assuming you know in advance the form of your struct.

Comment: I will indeed try this "casting to object" method. It seems pretty close to what I was looking for... though I don't like the idea of having a "mirror" object defined somewhere.

Comment: This is why I used the same variable name to overwrite the old struct. Good programming practice usually warns against the same variable holding different types, but I think in this case you can make an exception :)

Answer (score 5):

You should

1. define the variable in the function to be `persistent`
2. lock your function in the memory using `mlock`.

`mlock` locks the currently running function in memory so that subsequent `clear` functions do not remove it. Locking a function in memory also prevents any persistent variables defined in the file from getting reinitialized.

Comment: another solution if you're happy to use object oriented code, is to make your function a member function that initialises a property with the "constant" attribute

Comment: actually come to think of it, I think we both misinterpreted OP's question. I think they're after 'locking' the variable while still within the first pass of the function.

Comment: This is good to know, +1, but @Tasos Papastylianou's answer was closer to what I was looking for. I did not know about `mlock`!